# how to make multiple tkinter buttons to press together while as user presses any one of them?

Tags: python, tkinter

how to make multiple tkinter buttons to press together while as user presses any one of them?

To be clear i want multiple tkinter buttons look like pressed at the same time user presses any one of them .

i tried this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class one_for_all:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("One For All, All For One")

        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.btn1 = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="btn1", command=lambda : self.push_all(1))
        self.btn2 = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="btn2", command=lambda : self.push_all(2))
        self.btn3 = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="btn3", command=lambda : self.push_all(3))
        self.btn4 = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="btn4", command=lambda : self.push_all(4))


        self.btn1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.btn2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.btn3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.btn4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

        for child in self.frame.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

    def push_all(self, caller):
        if caller != 1:
            self.btn1.configure(command=lambda : None)
            self.btn1.event_generate("<ButtonPress-1>")
            self.btn1.event_generate("<ButtonRelease-1>")
            self.btn1.configure(command=lambda: self.push_all(1))
        if caller != 2:
            self.btn2.configure(command=lambda : None)
            self.btn2.event_generate("<ButtonPress-1>")
            self.btn2.event_generate("<ButtonRelease-1>")
            self.btn2.configure(command=lambda: self.push_all(2))
        if caller != 3:
            self.btn3.configure(command=lambda : None)
            self.btn3.event_generate("<ButtonPress-1>")
            self.btn3.event_generate("<ButtonRelease-1>")
            self.btn3.configure(command=lambda: self.push_all(3))
        if caller != 4:
            self.btn4.configure(command=lambda : None)
            self.btn4.event_generate("<ButtonPress-1>")
            self.btn4.event_generate("<ButtonRelease-1>")
            self.btn4.configure(command=lambda: self.push_all(4))

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    one_for_all().mainloop()
```

but it looks like only button 4 is stimulated by other buttons not all 4 :(
Note: i just started the tkinter without any prior experience of GUI

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button


class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.buttons = list()
        for i in range(4):
            button = Button(self, text=f'Button {i}')
            button.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.press)
            button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.release)
            button.pack(fill='both')
            self.buttons.append(button)

    def press(self, event=None):
        for btn in self.buttons:
            btn.config(relief='sunken')

    def release(self, event=None):
        for btn in self.buttons:
            btn.config(relief='raised')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow().mainloop()
```

It will visually make them appear to be clicked at once.

You can simply inherit from `Tk` and it will reduce the code written a bit since instead of `self.root` it would simply be just `self` and the features would be inherited and other stuff, for example, don't need to define `mainloop` as it is already inherited.

Also:
I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Have two blank lines around function and class declarations.

I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: Thank You For Help as well as advice i will surely gonna follow your advice and PEP 8